# Defining Setter/Getter for an unparented local variable: impossible?

Tags: javascript, scope, closures, local, setter

There's a few previous questions on StackOverflow questioning how one goes about accessing local variables via the scope chain, like if you wanted to reference a local variables using bracket notation and a string, you'd need something like `__local__["varName"]`. Thus far I haven't found even the hackiest method for accomplishing this, and haven't come up with a method after hours of exploiting every trick I know.

The purpose for it is to implement getters/setters on arbitrary unparented variables. Object.defineProperties or `__defineGet/Setter__` require a context to be called on. For properties in the global or window contexts you can accomplish the goal of having a setter/getter for direct references to the object.

```
Object.defineProperty(this, "glob", {get: function(){return "direct access"})
console.log(glob); //"direct access"
```

Even in my tests with a custom extension I compiled into a modified Chromium that runs prior to any window creation where the context is the actual global context, and even trying to call `this` directly in the global context *crashes* my program, I can pull this off without a hitch:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "define", {
    value: function(name, descriptor){
        Object.defineProperty(this, name, descriptor);
    }
};
define("REALLYglobal", {get: function(){ return "above window context"; }});
```

And it is then available in all frames created later as a global routed through the specified getter/setter. The old `__defineGet/Setter__` also works in that context without specifying what to call it on (doesn't work in Firefox though, the method above does).

So basically it's possible to define get/set guards for any variable on an object, including the window/global context with direct call to the object (you don't need `window.propname`, just `propname`). This is the issue with being unable to reference unparented scoped variables, being the only type that can be in an accessible scope but have no addressable container. Of course they're also the most commonly used too so it's not an edge case. This problem also transcends the current implementation of Proxies in ES6/Harmony since it's a problem specifically with being unable to address a local object's container with the language's syntax.

The reason I want to be able to do this is that it's the only barrier to allow overloading of most math operators for use in complex objects like arrays and hashes and deriving a complex resulting value. I need to be able to hook into the setter in cases where a value is being set on an object type I've set up for overloading. No problem if the object can be global or can be a contained in a parent object, which is probably what I'll just go with. It's still useful with `a.myObject`, but the goal is to make it as transparently usable as possible.

Not only that, but it'd just be really useful to be able to accomplish something like this:

```
var point3d = function(){
    var x, y, z;
    return {
        get: function(){ return [x, y, z]; },
        set: function(vals){ x=vals[0]; y=vals[1]; z=vals[2]; }
    };
};
```

(That is similar to ES6's destructuring but has more general applications for implementing functionality attached to getting/setting and not just transporting complex values). Even this basic code will completely fail:

```
var x = {myname: "intercept valueOf and :set: to overload math ops!", index: 5};
x++; //x is now NaN if you don't implement a setter somehow
```

I don't care how hacky the solution is, at this point it's just an intense curiosity for me as to whether it can be accomplished, even if it requires breaking every best practice that exists. I've crashed Firefox and Chrome a few hundred times in pursuit of this so far by doing things like redefining/intercepting/modifying `Object.prototype.valueOf/toString`, `Function.prototype` `Function.prototype.constructor`, `Function.prototype.call/apply`, `arguments.callee.caller`, etc. with infinite recursion errors and whatnot in attempts to jury rig contexts retroactively. The only thing that I've been able to make work is wrapping basically the whole thing with eval and dynamically building code chunks, which is a bridge too far for me to ever actually use. The only other remotely successful route was in using `with` combined with pre-defining all local variables on a container, but that's obviously very intrusive on top of the issues with using `with`.

Comment: `object.defineProperty` should work on `window`. However you can't create local variables since you can't access the `ScopeContext` programatically

Comment: You realise that the only way to manage this is compilation right. ([My attempt at compilation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851869/lightweight-javascript-to-javascript-parser))

Comment: This was kind of my last ditch effort to see if someone found a loophole that I didn't. I have a history of being able to find the solution one way or another, and this is my first question on StackOverflow because I ultimately came up empty after a lot of work.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this? Was there a real-life problem that led to this?

Comment: It can be worked around obviously, but it seems to be a glaring hole that does cause specific issues. The most common one I see people asking about being attempts to access local variables using bracket notation, which can be very useful. It just forces a more Class/Object oriented angle on things by requiring all the really useful/cool tricks to be done (syntactically) on members of a parent, or in the global context.

Comment: Self-setter/getter declaration (and the expansion of that kind of thing with Proxies in harmony) provide avenues for a lot of amazing fluencies, and they will not be available directly on any object which isn't parent addressable. Beyond that, I see a lot of potential for fluencies provided by operator overloading via methods similar to what I'm using, which require being able tap into settings.

Comment: @Brian i don't get why you don't get it ;) why someone would want to refer simply to "ipaddress", instead of "needlessobject.ipaddress" or "ipaddress()", seems self-explanatory to me

Comment: Please don't vandalize a question by removing valuable content that may help others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is currently possible in environments with Proxies. That would be node > 0.6 run as `node --harmony_proxies` or >0.7 with `node --harmony`. Chromium Canary (not sure if it's out of that yet) in about:flags at the bottom, experimental javascript. Firefox has had it for a while with no flags.

So this probably won't work when ES6 becomes more official, but it works to an extent now.

```
  var target = (function(){
    var handler = Proxy.create(Proxy.create({
      get: function(r, trap){
        return function(name,val,c,d){
          if (trap === 'get' || trap === 'set') {
            name = val;
            val = c;
          }
          console.log('"'+trap + '" invoked on property "'+name+'" ' + (val?' with value "'+val+'"':''));
          switch (trap) {
            case 'get': return target[name];
            case 'set': return target[name] = val;
            case 'has': return name in target;
            case 'delete': return delete target;
            case 'keys': return Object.keys(target);
            case 'hasOwn': return Object.hasOwnProperty.call(target, name);
            case 'getPropertyDescriptor':
            case 'getOwnPropertyDescriptor': return Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, name);
            case 'getPropertyNames':
            case 'getOwnPropertyNames': return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(target);
            case 'defineProperty': return Object.defineProperty(target, name, val);
          }
        }
      }
    }))

    var target = {
      x: 'stuff',
      f: { works: 'sure did' },
      z: ['overwritten?']
    };


    with (handler){
      var z = 'yes/no';
      if (x) {
        //x
      } else {
        x = true;
      }
      console.log(f.works);
      if (f.works) {
        f.works = true;
        delete f;
      }

    }
    return target
  })()
   // "getPropertyDescriptor" invoked on property "z" 
   // "getPropertyDescriptor" invoked on property "z" 
   // "getPropertyDescriptor" invoked on property "x" 
   // "get" invoked on property "x" 
   // "getPropertyDescriptor" invoked on property "console" 
   // "getPropertyDescriptor" invoked on property "f" 
   // "get" invoked on property "f" 
   // sure did
   // "getPropertyDescriptor" invoked on property "f" 
   // "get" invoked on property "f" 
   // "getPropertyDescriptor" invoked on property "f" 
   // "get" invoked on property "f" 
   // "getPropertyDescriptor" invoked on property "f" 

   target: { x: 'Stuff', f: { works: true },  z: ['overwritten?'] }
```

Hit or miss and you need to take care not to blow up your browser by simply looking at a Proxy in the debugger. I had to wrap that thing in a closure to keep the proxy from ending up in the global scope or it crashed the frame every single time. Point is that it works to some extent, where nothing else does.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the answer is **No**. I have been searching for behavior like this for quite a while. I have not been able to come up with any passable solution. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/598878/143739) seems similar. Python has the nice `locals` keyword.

Comment: Accepted answer of most likely impossible.

Answer (score 3):

Since you state you want similar behavior to `window/global`, I assumed you want this within a given context other that `window/global`. An easy way to do this is by using the `with` statement in combination with a `local` object and a `define` function which implement `Object.defineProperty` with `local` as target. You than simply place your own code within the `with` block.

IMPORTANT: `with` overloads the native local variables (`var, let, const`). Because of this it's very important to keep clear code, and to prevent duplicate names within the scope and parent/child contexts.

Lets start of with the context, in this case I use a closure, but this could also be a function, constructor or any other context.

```
// This closure represents any function, class or other scoped block.
(function (){

}());
```

Next we add the storage container and the `define` function. This is basically what you should always start with if you want access the local properties from anywhere in your code (within this scope).

```
// This is where we store the local property. (except: var, let, const)
const local = {};

// The define function is used to declare and define the local properties.
function define(name, descriptor){ Object.defineProperty(local, name, descriptor); }
```

Now you can place any code before the `with` statement but for this example we'll only add code that requires `local` in some way so the next step is creating the `with` statement.

```
// This with statement extends the current scope with local.
with(local){

    // This is where your code goes.

}
```

Now the outer structure of the `with` statement is ready, and we can start adding code inside the with statement.

All code placed within the `with` statement's block has access to the properties of `local` as if they where defined with for instance `var`, including properties defined within the `with` statement.

There are several ways to work with the properties of `local`. The easiest way to define a property is by setting it within 'local' directly. This only needs to be done once, after that the property is accessable by just it's name.

```
local.setDirectly = "directly set value";

console.log(setDirectly);    // logs "directly set value"
```

An other way to define a property, but than with support for `get/setters` as well as options on enumerabiliy and write access, is to use the `define` function. Expect the same behavior as from `Object.defineProperty`.

You could for instance add a `time` property that returns the current time.

```
define("time", {
    get: function(){
        var date = new Date();
        return date.getHours() + ":" + ("0" + date.getMinutes()).substr(-2);
    }
})

console.log(time);
```

Or you could create a counter property that increments each time it's accessed, placed within a nested closure to protect the counters own variable from unwanted changes.

```
(function (){
    var counterValue = 0;
    define("count", {get: function(){ return counterValue++ }});
}());

console.log(count);          // logs 0
console.log(count);          // logs 1
```

When you combine all this you will get something similar to the following code

```
// This closure represeents any function, class or other scoped block.
(function(){
    // This is where we store the local property. (except: var, let, const)
    const local = {};

    // The define function is used to declare and define the local properties.
    function define(name, descriptor){ Object.defineProperty(local, name, descriptor); }

    // This with statement extends the current scope with local.
    with(local){
        // This is where your code goes.

        // Defining a variable directly into local.
        local.setDirectly = "directly set value";
        console.log(setDirectly);    // logs "directly set value"
        // Defining local properties with the define function
        // For instance a time variable that return the current time (Hours:Minutes)
        define("time", {
            get: function(){
                var date = new Date();
                return date.getHours() + ":" + ("0" + date.getMinutes()).substr(-2);
            }
        })
        console.log(time);           // logs HH:MM

        // Or a counter property that increments each time it's been accessed.
        (function (){
            var counterValue = 0;
            define("count", {get: function(){ return counterValue++ }});
        }());
        console.log(count);          // logs 0
        console.log(count);          // logs 1
        console.log(count);          // logs 2
        console.log(count);          // logs 3
    }
}());
```

Like I mentioned before, it is important to understand the implications of using the `with` statement. More information on `with` can be found at [MDN - with](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with). As the question states, it's a search to how you could, not how you should. Use the information on MDN to see if it fits your situation.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this answers your question but this works:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'prop', {
get: function () {
    alert('you just got me')
},

set: function (val) {
    alert('you just set me')
},

configurable: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

For a solution just with basic objects:

```js
function ref (o)
{
    return new Proxy({}, new Proxy({}, {
        get (_, prop) { return (_, ...args) => Reflect[prop](o(), ...args) }
    }));
}
```

To work with DOM and primitive objects as well:

```js
function ref (o)
{
    return new Proxy({}, new Proxy({}, {
        get (_, prop) { return {
            get (_, prop) {
                let p = o(), r = p[prop];
                if (r instanceof Function) r = r.bind(p)
                return r 
            },
            set (_, prop, v) { o()[prop] = v },
            has (_, prop) { return prop in o() },
            keys(_, prop) { return Object.keys(o()) },
            apply (_, _this, args) { return Object.apply(o(), _this, args) },
            hasOwn (_, prop) { return Object.hasOwnProperty.call(o(), prop) },
            ownKeys() {
                var p = o();
                return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(p).concat(Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(p))
            },
            deleteProperty (_, prop) { return delete o()[prop] },
            defineProperty (_, prop, desc) { return Object.defineProperty(o(), prop, desc) },
            getOwnPropertyDescriptor (_, prop) { return Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o(), prop) }
        }[prop] ?? ((_, ...args) => Reflect[prop](o(), ...args));
    }}));
}

function refs (o)
{
    if (!(o instanceof Function)) o = (o => () => o)(o);
    return new Proxy({}, {
        get (_, prop) { return ref(() => o()[prop]) }
    })
}
```

#### Usage

```js
let vec = {x: 0, y: 1, z: 2};
let {x, y, z} = refs(() => vec);
outp(`X: ${x}. Y: ${y}. Z: ${z}`); // X: 0. Y: 1. Z: 2
vec.x = 3;
outp(`X: ${x}. Y: ${y}. Z: ${z}`); // X: 3. Y: 1. Z: 2
x = 1;
outp(vec.x); // 3

vec = {y: 1, z: 1};
outp(y === 1); // false
outp(y == 1); // true
outp(z == 1); // true
outp(y == z); // false
// You cannot directly compare these Proxy objects.
outp(y.valueOf() === z.valueOf()); // true
outp(y.valueOf() === 1); // true
outp(z.valueOf() === 1); // true
```

```js
function ref (o)
{
    return new Proxy({}, new Proxy({}, {
        get (_, prop) { return {
            get (_, prop) {
                    let p = o(), r = p[prop];
                if (r instanceof Function) r = r.bind(p)
                return r 
            },
            set (_, prop, v) { o()[prop] = v },
            has (_, prop) { return prop in o() },
            keys(_, prop) { return Object.keys(o()) },
            apply (_, _this, args) { return Object.apply(o(), _this, args) },
            hasOwn (_, prop) { return Object.hasOwnProperty.call(o(), prop) },
            ownKeys() {
                var p = o();
                return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(p).concat(Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(p))
            },
            deleteProperty (_, prop) { return delete o()[prop] },
            defineProperty (_, prop, desc) { return Object.defineProperty(o(), prop, desc) },
            getOwnPropertyDescriptor (_, prop) { return Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o(), prop) }
        }[prop] ?? ((_, ...args) => Reflect[prop](o(), ...args));
    }}));
}

function refs (o)
{
    if (!(o instanceof Function)) o = (o => () => o)(o);
    return new Proxy({}, {
        get (_, prop) { return ref(() => o()[prop]) }
    })
}

let text = '';
function emitText()
{
    document.body.appendChild(
        Object.assign(document.createElement('pre'),  {innerText: text})
    );
}
function outp (t)
{
    text += " // " + t;
}
function header (t)
{
    emitText();
    document.body.appendChild(
        Object.assign(document.createElement('h1'),  {innerText: t})
    );
    text = '';
}
function log (t)
{
    text += '\n' + t;
}

header("Usage");

let vec = {x: 0, y: 1, z: 2}; log('let vec = {x: 0, y: 1, z: 2};');
let {x, y, z} = refs(() => vec); log('let {x, y, z} = refs(() => vec);');

log('outp(`X: ${x}. Y: ${y}. Z: ${z}`);'); outp(`X: ${x}. Y: ${y}. Z: ${z}`);
vec.x = 3; log('vec.x = 3;');
log('outp(`X: ${x}. Y: ${y}. Z: ${z}`);'); outp(`X: ${x}. Y: ${y}. Z: ${z}`);

x = 1; log('x = 1;');
log('outp(vec.x);'); outp(vec.x);
log('');
vec = {y: 1, z: 1}; log('vec = {y: 1, z: 1};');
log('outp(y === 1);'); outp(y === 1);
log('outp(y == 1);'); outp(y == 1);
log('outp(z == 1);'); outp(z == 1);
log('outp(y == z);'); outp(y == z);
log('// You cannot directly compare these Proxy objects.');
log('outp(y.valueOf() === z.valueOf());'); outp(y.valueOf() === z.valueOf());
log('outp(y.valueOf() === 1);'); outp(y.valueOf() === 1);
log('outp(z.valueOf() === 1);'); outp(z.valueOf() === 1);

header('');
```