# ECMAScript 6 to ECMAScript 3 transpiler?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ecmascript-harmony, ecmascript-6

I'm familiar with the Google Traceur project (which is considered ready for production use in critical systems) as a transpiler from ECMAScript 6 to ECMAScript 5; unfortunately I still have to support IE 8 which is only compatible up to ECMAScript 3!

I'm curious if there are any projects out there to transpile from ECMAScript 6 to ECMAScript 3 so that I would be able to start utilizing ECMAScript 6 functionality now and then just switch over to that code base once IE8 is finally deprecated.

Comment: I don't know any, but es5-shim might work for you: https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506519/ecmascriptharmony-es6-to-javascript-compiler

Comment: @kangax, Thanks! Exactly what I was looking. BTW; I use your ES5/ES6 compat charts all the time; keep up the good work.